# Running a Macro through multiple Google Sheets without Copying & Pasting the Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Google Apps Script. I created a Macro in Excel with VBA. My process is downloading a CSV that I save to my hard drive, opening it (my PERSONAL workbook is open at all times) and then running my macro which will format the list/perform the steps of my macro. I would then save and manually upload that list back to Google Drive.

This is obviously inefficient and The rest of my team uses Google Drive/ Google Sheets and so I am attempting to teach myself how to build out the same macro in Google Apps Script. I understand the difference between bound and unbound scripts - this is similar to Excel in the sense that if I wanted to run my macro on multiple sheets, I would have to save it to my PERSONAL spreadsheet where I stored all of my macros and then have that sheet open at the same time that I ran the macro on a different spreadsheet.

However, for Google Apps Script, it appears as though you simply cannot run a macro through multiple different workbooks without manually copying and pasting your code to every new spreadsheet. Is this true? I see that it could be added in the app store and published as an add-on but my script is painfully basic, I'm just changing some words and formatting. It seems odd that this cannot be applied to multiple spreadsheets the way that it can in Excel. My goal was to use something like:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu('List Upload')
      .addItem('Format List Upload', 'formatListUpload')
      .addToUi();
```

where formatListUpload would run my formatting script so that my coworkers could just click "Format List Upload" as a menu option and the new spreadsheet they had just opened would be quickly formatted. This seems like base-level functionality for macros/ app script. Is there truly no way that this can be done?

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question

> However, for Google Apps Script, it appears as though you simply cannot run a macro through multiple different workbooks without manually copying and pasting your code to every new spreadsheet. Is this true?

No

> Is there truly no way that this can be done?

Instead of using a simple trigger you might use an installable trigger, but this option is limited to create 20 triggers by script / user. To make this work you will need somehow to open the spreadsheet i.e. `SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)`

---

Options to avoid having to create an add-on

One option that doesn't requires installable triggers is to submit the spreadsheet having the macro to the templates gallery and use the template to create the new spreadsheets

Another option is use script to create a new spreadsheet and the installable trigger for it.

One more option is to create a new spreadsheet, grab the spreadsheet id, either manually or programmatically, then use it to create the installable trigger for the new spreadsheet.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. However, I am not sure how I would be expected to anticipate what the spreadsheetId will be... the process is that 1. a different stakeholder creates a spreadsheet. 2. This is imported to a board, 3. A coworker opens the spreadsheet based on the shared URL, 4. They should be able to run the macro. How would I know which SpreadsheetIds I would need?

Comment: Are you open to change the process?

Comment: Yes, this would be fine. We currently upload the spreadsheets based on a template to a Monday board but they still need to be cleaned after the stakeholder inputs the data

Comment: Added some options to the answer.